# Netgear A6200 USB Modem does not work on Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: wireless, 12.10, netgear

My Netgear A6200 USB Modem does not work with Ubuntu 12.10 running on either a i7(2.4 Mhz w/8GB RAM, two 500GB HDs & eight USB 2.0 ports) desktop or a HP/Compaq Mini 110c Netbook (running 12.04). The A6200 modem is simply not recognized. Several older Netgear modems work with Ubuntu 12-10 fine. I tried A6200 on Wine and on a virtual Windows disk, but that was no help. The A6200 does work fine on Windows Vista and Windows 8 computers.

Any chance that there is a usable driver out there for this modem? Or any other way to get it to work with Ubuntu 12.10?

Answer (score 0):

[Netgear A6200 wireless adapter Drivers for linux](http://www.mediafire.com/?od9wpw6ccrnyhaa)

Use ndiswrapper to install .inf file in above zip file worked for me in ubuntu 11.04

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: only 2.4G works with this driver, 5G does not work.

Answer (score 0):

According to a post on this [thread](http://forum1.netgear.com/showthread.php?t=79948), it is possible.

Short version:

1. Install ndis-wrapper
2. a. Install Wine

   b. Run the Windows installer via Wine

   The installer will fail, but before doing so it should output the drivers we need to `<wine drive location>/Program Files/netgear/A6200/Driver`. (That'll be somewhere like `.wine/drive_c/Program Files/...`)
3. Use those drivers with ndis-wrapper.

As an alternative to step 2, you could use the files provided in that thread (or provided here) (both apparently by the same mooms), but that implies trusting a 3rd party (other than netgear).

Disclaimer: I haven't tried this yet.